# Linux find command and copy and rename them same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

Will you be able to help me to write a script, I just want to find log files over 2GB and copy them to archive folder in same directory.I just write a find command it is not working, appreciate if someone could help me.

ex - main log folders - /vsapp/logs/
                                    - app1,app2,app3
there are lot of logs in the app1, app2 and app3 folders.

so i want to find the logs in the logs folder which is over 2GB, and copy them to archive folder with the different name with today's date.

ex - abcd.log -----copy to -----> abcd.log-08-22-2016

My command at the moment which is not working

```
find $i/* -type f -size +2G -exec cp '{}' $i/$arc/{}-$date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
find /src -type f -name '*.log' -size +2G -exec cp {} /dest/{}-$(date -I) \;
```

Additions/Modifications i made:

- `-name '*.log'` searches only for log files, as we are only interested in those. You can look for files with any names too if unsure, just omit `-name '*.log` in that case
- `$(date -I)` is command substitution the output will be today's date in format `YYYY-mm-dd`, you can also define a custom format, check `man date`
- End the `-exec` action of `find` with `\;`

Comment: find . -type f -size +2G -exec cp {} archive/{}-date \; try this but wont work, it is not copy , im testing by creating one file wchi size of 2GB.

Comment: @SLS Check my command again. You need `find . -type f -size +2G -exec cp {} archive/{}-$(date -I) \;`

Comment: Nop friend, which not copy to archive folder.

Comment: @SLS are you sure you have done this in the right manner? Can you get the file name with `find . -type f -size +2G`?

Comment: Sorry  Heemayl, You answer is correct, I have created dum file, but it is not actualy showing correct files size that is the issue, i have coped realy log file and tested it. it is working thank you very much for the support, I will make this as as resolved